# How to refer to a doubly-templated free function in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class within which I define free functions taking references to that templated class.  These free functions are also templated on a different parameter.

From outside the class I can call the free functions.  However, I cannot find the correct syntax for one free function to call another.

Quick example:

```
template<typename T> class Foo {
  template<typename S>
  friend S f(const Foo &) { return S(); }

  template<typename S>
  friend S g(const Foo &s) {
    return f(s);  // See below, when instantiated, yields 'no matching function for call to f(const Foo &)'
  }
};

float test1() {
  Foo<int> o;
  return f<float>(o); // Compiles
}

float test2() {
  Foo<int> o;
  return g<float>(o); // Fails to compile as line above errors
}
```

(c.f. [this link](http://url.godbolt.org/dlcht) too)

It seems by the point of the call to f(s) within g(), the outermost template has been lost.  How might I re-specify the T in the call to f?  I have checked on GCC4.7, 4.8, clang 3.2 all with equivalent errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `f(s)` you need to specify the template parameter `S` because it can't be deduced from the argument `s`.

But if you change it to `f<S>(s)` (assuming you meant to call it with the same template argument `S`  as `g` was called with) then you inhibit ADL, and the only way a friend function defined at class scope can be found is by ADL.  So you need to add a declaration of `f` to the global namespace, so that the call in `g` can find it.

So to make it work you need to add these declarations before `Foo`

```
template<typename T> class Foo;

template<typename S, typename T>
  S f(const Foo<T> &);

template<typename S, typename T>
  S g(const Foo<T> &);
```

and change the call in `g` to be `f<S>(s)` or something else like `f<x>(s)`

Comment: Can you show what that declaration would look like?  Templated friends  accepting templated arguments do not have simple syntax.

Comment: Thanks - that's perfect.  My final solution is:
    template<typename... T> class Foo {
    };

    template<typename S, typename... T>
    S f(const Foo<T...> &) { return S(); }

    template<typename S, typename... T>
    S g(const Foo<T...> &o) { return f<S, T...>(o); }

    float test2() {
      Foo<int> o;
      return g<float>(o);
    }

Comment: Ok, so what makes that the correct order of the template arguments to match the friend definition?

Comment: @BenVoigt, I tried it with both g++ and clang++ and it worked, so I was happy with that :-P

Comment: @Jonathan: It definitely works.  I just would have expected `template<typename T> template<typename S> S f(const Foo<T>&);` and was wondering why the template arguments get rolled together.  I guess because it's not a member function.

Comment: Right, the `template<typename T>template<typename S>` form is for a member template of a class template, this isn't a member. I'll try to find the wording that covers it ...